# Downloading Excel File from XLConnect with R Shiny

Tags: r, excel, download, shiny, xlconnect

Has anyone tried using the download handler in R Shiny to download a freshly created Excel file with XLConnect?

In the ui.R there is the unremarkable line:

```
downloadButton('downloadData', 'Download')
```

In the server.R there is the handler:

```
output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(

filename = function() { "output.xlsx" },

    content = function(file){
      wb <- loadWorkbook(file, create = TRUE)
      createSheet(wb, name = "Sheet1")
      writeWorksheet(wb, c(1:3), sheet = "Sheet1") # writes numbers 1:3 in file
      saveWorkbook(wb)
    }
)
```

I have no problem downloading a .csv and no problem creating the excel file with XLConnect. But when I run the code as above I get the following error in my Chrome browser:

> IllegalArgumentException (Java): File extension "file1b683b9323bc" not
>   supported! Only *.xls and *.xlsx are allowed!

As far as I can see, XLConnect cannot write to a temporary file.

Has anyone got a solution or workaround?

One option would be to save the file in a specific location and then creating a download link pointing to it. However, this is not very Shiny-esque as multiple users would cause havok.

Many Thanks

Marcus

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try using this for the `content(...)` function; it works for me...

```
content = function(file){
      fname <- paste(file,"xlsx",sep=".")
      wb <- loadWorkbook(fname, create = TRUE)
      createSheet(wb, name = "Sheet1")
      writeWorksheet(wb, c(1:3), sheet = "Sheet1") # writes numbers 1:3 in file
      saveWorkbook(wb)
      file.rename(fname,file)
    }
```

The problem is that `file` is a randomly generated temp file, without an extension, whereas `saveWorkbook(...)` requires the `.xlsx` extension. So this just appends `.xlsx` to `file` and uses that for all the XLConnect manipulations, then renames the final file to the original name (e.g., strips off the extension).

Comment: When I use saveWorkbook(wb) it gives me an error saying that the file parameter is required